# Django admin - How to add a link to table's page that allow set a value for a column

Tags: django, django-admin

For example, I have a table's page in Django admin as follow:
[Django admin table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv3s8.png)
I want all devices will have same "Regulations Url" and "Regulations Version", so I want to add a link button like button "Add Device". This link will point to a page that allows change value of 2 columns "Regulations Url" and "Regulations Version" of all devices on the table.

Does anyone have work around this problem, Thanks!

Update: This is my model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
   device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   device_version = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   regulations_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   regulation_version = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.device_name
```

Comment: Can you please add code snippet

Comment: @NitheeshMN I added my model above, Let's me know if there is anything that doesn't clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this problem is using custom javascript and modal window.

**step 1** : **Adding custom button and modal window**

Add a button using javascript and bind a on-click event to that button( You can inject html using javascript better use Jquery), connect that to a view function using url. That view should return html for a modal window containing two text boxes to enter values you want to update for all fields and one button "update". After getting the response(html) from the view, in javascript event handler attach the html model with the current django admin html.

After this step you will be able to see a button in the list display page of the admin, and clicking on that button you will see a modal window pop up with two text box and one button.

**step 2**: **Adding update action on the modal window button**

Add a click event on the modal "update" and connect that to a view using url. Pass the new values to that view function. Inside the view function update the fields with the new value for all objects. Add command to close the modal window
inside the event handler of "update" button.